# Proving system of bilinear equations does not have a solution using convex optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, problem-solving, matrix-rank

Consider a collection of $m$ matrices $A_i$ of size $n\times n$, and a vector $b$ of size $m$. Collecting variables into two vectors $x,y$ of size $n$, I have the bilinear system of equations:

$$\left\{ x^T A_i y = b_i : i = 1,\dots,m \right\}.$$

I would like to consider the domain of the variables to be the complex numbers.

What techniques are available to prove such a system has no solution?

---

In case it helps, the particular problem I am interested in has $A_i$ and $b$ real valued.

Furthermore, the $A_i$ are such for any pair of values of $j$, $k$ the term $x_j y_k$ will only be used by at most one $A_i$ constraint. (The latter sounds quite constraining, but I couldn't figure out how to use it effectively.

---

Here is an interesting approach suggested on mathoverflow for solving such systems:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308163/solving-system-of-bilinear-equations

The suggestion is to linearize it into a system of equations on the elements of the matrix $Z = x y^T$. Such a matrix (as long as zero is not a solution) must have rank 1. Then we may use convex optimization: the constraints are now linear, and optimize the solution with the objective to minimize $||Z||_{*}$ the [nuclear norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms) which is a proxy for the rank.

I do not understand this method well enough to understand if it is guaranteed to work if there is a solution. In particular, I'd like to invert the argument: if I optimize and get a matrix with rank>1, can I therefore conclude that there is no solution to the original problem?

Comment: sounds like the nuclear norm is hard enough to calculate that solvers approximate it, and so maybe this wouldn't really allow a proof anyway ... just give strong evidence there is no solution? or maybe with certain conditions the approximation still works?

Comment: Considering how "sparse" and "non-interacting" my linearized constraints would be, maybe there is a way to do this without approximating the nuclear norm. For example, with at most one constraint referring to each $x_j y_k$ maybe there is some straightforward change of coordinates which simultaneously diagonalizes all the $A_i$ ...  hmmm, no because then that would allow $Z$ to be rank 1. Grrr. I feel like I'm missing a much simpler option.